# Struggling with adding new theme colours in UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So I've got someone who uses a UWP program and they're dyslexic and asked if the background and text colours could be changed to make it easier for them to read the text. Currently the app has light, dark and default theme that were there from the template and I've not touched them.
I've worked out I can edit colours of the dark/light/default with the below added to the App.xaml file. (I've only put one brush colour to test). Ideally I'd prefer to add another theme, rather than editing the basic themes. Is there somewhere that details how to do this?

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush" Color="BlueViolet" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush" Color="IndianRed" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush" Color="DarkOliveGreen" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently UWP cannot add additional themes, [RequestedTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme?view=winrt-22621#property-value) can only choose `Light` and `Dark`.

You can try using [Contrast themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/accessibility/high-contrast-themes), and users can also set the color which is suitable for them in Setting > Accessibility > Contrast themes.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically adjust the colours? Say if a user clicks something then SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush would change to a different colour?